# Find all the angles $v$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Find all the angles $v$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ such that

$$-\sin(v)+ \sqrt3 \cos(v) = \sqrt2$$

The answer has to be in the form of: $\pi/2$ (it must include $\pi$)

I have tried squaring but I get nowhere.

Comment: Between $\pi$ and $\pi$?

Comment: Do you mean "between $-\pi$ and $\pi$"?

Comment: @Arthur Yes sorry I will correct it

Answer (score 7):

It's sometimes a good idea to turn a sum of sines and cosines into a single trigonometric term when solving equations of the form $a \sin x + b\cos x = c$, in this case: $$\sqrt{3}\cos v - \sin v \equiv 2\cos \left(v + \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$

So, if you set $x = v + \frac{\pi}{6}$ you need only solve $\cos x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ which you can then do, I'm sure.

Comment: Should this really be considered hint? I mean, it's a good answer, but I think it's much more than a hint...

Comment: @5xum fair enough, I've edited the answer to acknowledge. :)

Comment: @ZainPatel I don't understand the first equation. Why are they equivalent?

Comment: @DoubleOseven I wasn't home and was planning to type out an explanation, but bthmas has said everything I was planning to in his answer. :-)

Comment: @ZainPatel teamwork makes the dream work (:

Answer (score 4):

Divide the equation by $\;2\;$ :

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}=-\frac12\sin x+\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos x=\sin\frac\pi3\cos x-\cos\frac\pi3\sin x=\sin\left(\frac\pi3-x\right)\implies$$

$$\frac\pi3-x=\begin{cases}\cfrac\pi4\\{}\\\cfrac{3\pi}4\end{cases}\implies \ldots$$

Observe this is similar to the other answer but, perhaps, a little, very little, easier to understand.

Comment: (+1) This is better than my answer.

Comment: @ZainPatel Thank you. Once upon a time I had to teach my kids some basic trigonometry, and I still remember that *this kind* of equations can be solved, many times, with this kind of identities

Answer (score 0):

As noted by another user, it's useful to combine a sum of sines and cosines into a single function.
$$
\sqrt{3}\cos(v) - \sin(v) = \sqrt{2}
$$
In order to turn the LHS into a single function we have a bit of a choice here we can make the single function a sine or a cosine, and we can also choose if we want an addition or subtraction in the angle.

For this I'll show how to do it with a subtraction in the angle and a cosine function.

Recall from the angle difference formula for cosine
$$
\cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
$$
Now we set the equality
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{3}\cos(v) - \sin(v) &= A\cos(v -\theta)\\
\sqrt{3}\cos(v) - \sin(v) &= A \left [ \cos(v)\cos(\theta) + \sin(v)\sin(\theta) \right ]\\
\sqrt{3}\cos(v) - \sin(v) &= A\cos(\theta)\cos(v) + A\sin(\theta)\sin(v)
\end{align}
$$
From here we equate the coefficients
$$
\begin{align}
A\cos(\theta) &= \sqrt{3}\\
A\sin(\theta) &= -1
\end{align}
$$
Solving for $\theta$ gives
$$
\tan(\theta) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} \implies \theta = \frac{-\pi}{6}
$$
Solving for $A$ gives
$$
A\cos \left ( \frac{-\pi}{6} \right ) = \sqrt{3} \implies A\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \sqrt{3} \implies A = 2
$$

Therefore, 
$$
\sqrt{3}\cos(v) - \sin(v) = 2\cos(v +\frac{\pi}{6})
$$

Just make this substitution, and I'm sure you can do the rest.